# Regex not working in Sitecore Forms

Tags: sitecore-forms, regex

In Sitecore 10 forms, I am trying a very simple regex

```
 {"regularExpression":"^(?:\+[0-9]{9,}|[0-9]{10,})$"}
```

This regular expression matches strings that either start with a plus sign followed by at least 9 digits or consist of at least 10 digits alone. The plus sign at the start is optional, and the overall minimum length is 10 characters

This is not even showing in the front-end. The attribute **data-val-regex-pattern is missing.

I tried this regex `{"regularExpression":"^[0-9]*$"}` which is working and also showing the attribute **`data-val-regex-pattern="^[0-9]*$"`**
but not the regex with option to have '+' sign in the start.

Is there anything I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We faced similar issue after creating a new field validator. Surprisingly, `RegularExpressionValidation` could not evaluate `this.Parameters?.RegularExpression`
So we created a custom regex validator,

```
//Sitecore namespace - Sitecore.ExperienceForms.Mvc.Models.Validation
public class CustomRegularExpressionValidation : ValidationElement<RegularExpressionParameters>
{
public override void Initialize(object validationModel)
    {
      base.Initialize(validationModel);
      if (validationModel is StringInputViewModel stringInputViewModel)
        this.Title = stringInputViewModel.Title;
      // This was not evaluating as expected      
      //this.RegularExpression = this.Parameters?.RegularExpression ?? string.Empty;
      // so added this
      this.RegularExpression = this.ValidationItem.Parameters ?? string.Empty; 
    }
}
```