# Validate Date entered is in yyyy/mm/dd format in Sitecore Forms

Tags: sitecore-forms, validation, regex

I have a text field in the Sitecore form where the user needs to enter a Date.
Currently, I am using Regex Validator that check date in `mm/dd/yyyy` format.

Need support to check if the date is in `yyyy/mm/dd` format.

```
{"regularExpression":"^((0[13578]|1[02])[/]31[/](18|19|20)[0-9]{2})|((01|0[3-9]|1[1-2])[/](29|30)[/](18|19|20)[0-9]{2})|((0[1-9]|1[0-2])[/](0[1-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-8])[/](18|19|20)[0-9]{2})|((02)[/]29[/](((18|19|20)(04|08|[2468][048]|[13579][26]))|2000))$"}
```

The above regex I am currently using.

Comment: Welcome to SSE @Abhinav. Can you please elaborate on a problem you are facing ? Is it that none regex works? Or one works and other doesn't...

Comment: The above regex validate date in mm/dd/yyyy format and is working as expected.
I need support to validate in yyyy/mm/dd format and need regex for that.

Comment: Btw I faced a similar issue with value not being validated against regex. You can take a look at it as well. https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/35323/regex-not-working-in-sitecore-forms/35325#35325

Comment: Checked the above links. The regex is working for me in mm/dd/yyyy format. But I am not able to modify regex to check date is in yyyy/mm/dd format.

Comment: Apologies, I misread. Deleted that comment. Please check this link - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5247219/regular-expression-to-detect-yyyy-mm-dd

Comment: Tried following above link. not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to reorder regex parts like that:

```
{"regularExpression":"^((18|19|20)[0-9]{2}[/](0[13578]|1[02])[/]31)|((18|19|20)[0-9]{2}[/](01|0[3-9]|1[1-2])[/](29|30))|((18|19|20)[0-9]{2}[/](0[1-9]|1[0-2])[/](0[1-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-8]))|((((18|19|20)(04|08|[2468][048]|[13579][26]))|2000)[/](02)[/]29)$"}
```

Now year goes first, then month and then day.

Comment: It worked. Thanks.

Comment: Then you can mark the answer as correct.