# we have requirement to block the free emails from submitting the sitecore-forms Is there any way to block the free emails(gmail,yahoo,...)?

Tags: sitecore-forms

We are using `Sitecore 10.3 XM` and `Sitecore forms` and we have a requirement to block the free emails to fill the forms. I tried implementing the default email validation by changing its `regExp` in the parameters but it's not working as per the expecting. It's accepting the free emails.

regExp:

```
{"regularExpression":"^(?!(?:[a-zA-Z0-9_\\-.]+@(?:yahoo\\.com|gmail\\.com|hotmail\\.com))).*$"}
```

[image]

Also included this validation on the forms.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to SSE Harshit. Have you checked this ? https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/35323/regex-not-working-in-sitecore-forms/35325#35325

Comment: Even if you DO manage to find a technical solution to filtering the domains, there is just no way you could ever hope to filter out "free email domains". You're listing 3 here, there are literally thousands of them.